# Property does not exists on type when destructuring assignment and 'Pick' in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to use the interface defined in the model as the argument of a function.

```
// model/interface.ts
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface Post extends Document {
  location: {
    type: string;
    coordinates: number[];
  };
};

// service/post_create.ts
import { Post } from '../../model/interface/post';

const exec = async (location: Pick<Post, 'location'>) => {
  const { coordinates: [x, y] } = location;
  // -> Property 'coordinates' does not exists on type 'Pick<Post, 'location'>'
}
```

I've specified a type via Pick, which I've imported to use the interface as a function argument, but I can't actually find a property named "coordinates" inside the function.

What did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Pick` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) is used to "filter" keys of the object type, so if you say

```
type X = Pick<Post, 'location'>
/*
It means:
X = {
  location: {
    type: string;
    coordinates: number[];
  };
}
*/
```

As you can see we have object type with picked properties only, in your example we picked one - `location`. But that means `location` is a property in this object and in order to access it you need to say `location.location`.

---

Looking at your use case, I think you want to get type of `location` property and not filtered object. Getting property type can be done by [indexed types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html). Consider:

```
const exec = async (location: Post['location']) => {
  const { coordinates: [x, y] } = location; // works
}
```

`Post['location']` takes type of `location` property of the `Post` type.

Answer (score 1):

Location contains location

```
const exec = async (location: Pick<Post, 'location'>) => {
  const { coordinates: [x, y] } = location.location;
}
```